# WPF ContentPresenter failed to bind Visibility

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I´m having trouble with binding the Visibility of a ContentPresenter. I created a minimal example Window:

In my Resources I defined the following DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Window contains just StackPanel of a red and green filled border.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" Visibility="{Binding Vis}"/>
    <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green" Visibility="{Binding Vis}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The Visibility is available in the DataContext:

```
private Visibility _Vis;
public Visibility Vis
{
    get
    {
        return _Vis;
    }
    set
    {
        _Vis = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Vis));
    }
}
```

Showing the Window, the two borders are shown among each other. Now **the problem:** If I change the Visibility (OnPropertyChanged used), only the green border changes the Visibility. The red border using the ContentTemplate does not change it´s Visibility. But both Controls are bound to the same property!

- I tried it with `Collapsed` and `Hidden` - no difference
- I also tried adding `DataContext={Binding}` to the ContentPresenter -
  no difference

What is the problem of using a ContentPresenter and bind it´s Visibility?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: ContentPresenter is special sometimes -- can you do replace it with a ContentControl (bind Content explicitly if you need to) and see if it works any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce what you're seeing, and I was able to fix it by changing the `ContentPresenter` to a `ContentControl`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl 
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" 
        Visibility="{Binding Vis}"
        />
    <Border 
        Width="50" 
        Height="50" 
        Background="Green" 
        Visibility="{Binding Vis}"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

`ContentPresenter` is a little funny. Others have had the same problem as you. As a rule, if I'm setting any properties on the thing, I change to a `ContentControl` instead. I assume you'll have to bind `Content` explicitly now on the `ContentControl`, which I hope won't be too much hassle.